# SMART TAG EXCEL

Tags: excel

Buen dìa,

Recurro a ustedes chicos ¡porque necesito ayuda!

Veran en Office 2013 Professional no me aparece la lista de acciones, y sin la acciòn DATE(XML) un archivo (XLBS) creado por nuestro equipo de reportes no funciona. La verdad me gustarìa saber si estas acciones pueden agregarse y porque en otros ordenadores si aparece.

Les dejo una imagen de esta lista de acciones o smart tags.

[image: Como se ve en la màquina con problemas]

[image: Como deberìa verse]

Agradezco toda su ayuda y quedo atenta.